# Restlet after few requests generate load on CPU

Tags: java, restlet

I have problem with API that I am creating. I am using Restlet for create API with json response. First of all I read documentation of restlet and I use simple model that they introduce here: http://restlet.org/discover/firststeps

My code is pretty much the same but some parts. My **ServerResource** is this:

```
public class CategoriesResource extends ServerResource {

    @Get("json")
    public StringRepresentation represent(Representation entity) {
        dbOperations db = new dbOperations();
        db.connect();

        Series<Header> responseHeaders = (Series<Header>) getResponse().getAttributes().get("org.restlet.http.headers");
        if (responseHeaders == null) {
        responseHeaders = new Series(Header.class);
        getResponse().getAttributes().put("org.restlet.http.headers", responseHeaders);
        }
        responseHeaders.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); 
        return new StringRepresentation(db.getCategoriesJson(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }

}
```

I creating json response with gson library in db operations I have lines:

```
CategoriesGson json = null;
json = new CategoriesGson(a, b, c, d);
// databases operations, most getting information from database
jsonList.add(gson.toJson(json));
return jsonList.toString();
```

Main problem is with CPU load when I press F5 after few times I get a lot of load on CPU. I was searching problem with that and I was able to do dump of thread is giving this usage.

```
Restlet-9860934" prio=10 tid=0x8828d000 nid=0x12ee runnable [0x87f89000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2854)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:128)
    at org.restlet.engine.connector.Way.toString(Way.java:594)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2854)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:128)
    at org.restlet.engine.connector.Way.onSelected(Way.java:471)
    at org.restlet.util.SelectionRegistration.onSelected(SelectionRegistration.java:325)
    at org.restlet.engine.connector.Connection.onSelected(Connection.java:612)
    - locked <0x937a7550> (a java.nio.HeapByteBuffer)
    at org.restlet.util.SelectionRegistration.onSelected(SelectionRegistration.java:325)
    at org.restlet.engine.connector.ConnectionController.onSelected(ConnectionController.java:219)
    at org.restlet.engine.connector.ServerConnectionController.onSelected(ServerConnectionController.java:99)
    at org.restlet.engine.connector.ConnectionController.selectKeys(ConnectionController.java:308)
    at org.restlet.engine.connector.ConnectionController.doRun(ConnectionController.java:171)
    at org.restlet.engine.connector.Controller.run(Controller.java:159)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

This is restlet thread and I think this is it fault. I have not idea how I can fix that. I was searching for this issue and I found only issue 386 and 794 on github. If someone have some idea how I can fix that please let me know.

Comment: I manage to find that CPU usage is high when I do multiple requests to server and this problem occur when request are not finished properly.

Answer (score 0):

I was having exactly the same bug and I just figured out how to reproduce it:

```
public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
    Router router = new Router(getContext());
    ChallengeAuthenticator authenticator = new ChallengeAuthenticator(getContext(), ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC, "cancel");

    Verifier verifier = new Verifier() {        // not even used
        @Override
        public int verify(Request arg0, Response arg1) {
            return Verifier.RESULT_VALID;
        }
    };

    authenticator.setVerifier(verifier);
    router.attach("/test", HelloResource.class);

    Authorizer authorizer = new Authorizer() {      // authorizer only being used to delay request          
        @Override
        protected boolean authorize(Request arg0, Response arg1) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);                 // request is delayed by 5000ms
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    authorizer.setNext(router);

    authenticator.setNext(authorizer);
    return authenticator;
}
```

So what I did was pretty simple. I delayed the request by 5s.
When I request a resource in my browser I cancel the request right away. Afterwards my CPU usage goes up to 100% and keeps at that level ...

Comment: exact same problem here, how do?